# THREE.js Irregular Polyhedron with gradient texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, gradient

I have a irregular polyhedron. I want to make the top/bottom face gradient.

with the box geometry, i implement it .

// gradient cavas

```
var canvas = $("#canvasTest")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
context.rect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
gradient.addColorStop( 0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop( 0.25, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop( 0.5, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop( 0.75, 'pink');
gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'black');
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fill();
```

//material

```
var materials = [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#6092c1',
                        // map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                      } ),
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#6092c1',
                        // map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                      } ), 
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#ffffff',
                        map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        overdraw:true,
                      } ),
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#ffffff',
                        map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        overdraw:true,
                      } ),
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#6092c1',
                        // map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                      } ), 
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color:'#6092c1',
                        // map:shadowTexture,
                        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                      } )
    ];
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
```

//box geometry

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 100, 1000, 20, 1, 20);
var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, faceMaterial);
```

finally like this:
[the box geometry result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc2cQ.png)

Then use above code, the irregular polyhedron does not work.

```
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(firstFloorGeometry, faceMaterial); //faceMaterial same to above 
        floor.name = "Floor";
        floor.position.y = 215;
        floor.position.x = -137;
        floor.position.z = 47;
        floor.receiveShadow = true;
        floor.scale.set(500, 500, 500);
        world.add(floor);
```

the result is :
[the irregular polyhedron geometry result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAqXM.png)

so is there any one can help me ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Does your `PolyhedronGeometry` have the UV's setup correctly?

Comment: NO, the PolyhedronGeometry is other send to me. I'll learn knowledge of UV. thanks you